# SSRS expression (subtraction from same field)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've a table with columns `Type` and `Amount`. `Type` can take only two values - 'A' and 'B', and `Amount` is numeric.

How to write an expression (I'll use it in indicators) to return

(sum of Amounts where Type = 'A') minus (sum of Amounts where Type = 'B')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IIF` something like:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "A", CDbl(Fields!Amounts.Value)), 0)) -
 SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "B", CDblFields!Amounts.Value)), 0))
```

Comment: thanks, but an error which I can't figure out occur: The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox30.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggreagete function. Tha scope parameter should be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containg group, the name of a containing data region or the name of a dataset. What does that mean. I've tried to test it by inserting expression into textbox

Comment: Updated an answer, check It out. Try to use `CDbl`.

Comment: @Stanislavos, the same error. Maybe here we can not sum on row basis?

Comment: I guess I should write a dataset. wait, I'll try

Comment: Yes, If you use multiple datesets, you have to provide them.